# What Java class allows to write to a file, both in Binary and ASCII?

Tags: java, file-writing

I need to write files, with Headers in ASCII and values in Binary.

For now, I'm using this:

```
File file = new File("~/myfile");
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
// Write in ASCII
out.write(("This is a header\n").getBytes());
// Write a byte[] is quite easy
byte[] buffer = new buffer[4];
out.write(buffer, 0, 4);
// Write an int in binary gets complicated
out.write(ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(6).array());
//Write a float in binary gets even more complicated
out.write(ByteBuffer.allocate(4).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN)
        .putFloat(4.5).array());
```

The problem is that it's very slow (in terms of performance) to write that way, way slower than writing the values in ASCII actually. But it should be shorter since in I'm writing less data.

I've looked at other Java classes, and it seems to me that they are either only for ASCII writing, or only for Binary writing.

Would you have any other proposition for this problem ?

Comment: You can wrap the stream into a Writer, use the Writer to write the characters, flush it, then continue using the stream directly to write the bytes.

Comment: Okay, I think I approximately see what you mean in terms of code.
The problem is, I think the part that takes the most time is writing ints and floats using the big code cluster wth ByteBuffer.
Is there a class that has methods like writeInt(), writeFloat(), with some parameters for endianness for example ?
So using a Writer would only simplify the "myString".getBytes() part.

Comment: DataOutputStream. You could also encapsulate the transformation of primitive types to bytes in utility methods instead of repeating the same code again and again.

Comment: Great ! "J'essaye ça et je te redis" as we say in French.

Comment: Mixing binary/raw data in text files is a bad idea. It makes it near impossible to edit without using custom tools. Java doesn't provide much in the way of parsing those kinds of files. You can look at DataOutputStream/DataInputStream which can handle primitive writing/reading with some basic handling for Strings. I would suggest choosing one or the other. Text for readability or raw for space.

Comment: Any mechanism that can write binary can write ASCII.

Comment: @JBNizet, Encapsulate the transformation of primitive types to bytes would simplify the code, but in execution, the same amount of code would be executed, so technically, it would take the same time, wouldn't it ?

Comment: @Smith_61, I agree with you, but in that case, I don't have much choice since I have to use a format not controlled by me...
But thank you, I'll look more into DataOutputStream.

Comment: @matthieu I thought that what bothered you was the tediousness of writing the code, rather than its performance. Allocating a byte buffer for each primitive is probably what kills your performance.

Comment: You're right, I wasn't clear enough on that adjective "long". I edited my question. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use FileOutputStream to write binary.  To include text you have to convert it to a byte[] before writing to the stream.

> The problem is that it's very long to write that way, way longer than writing the values in ASCII actually. But it should be shorter since in I'm writing less data.

Mixing text and data is complex and error prone.  The size of the data does matter, rather the complexity of the data is important.  I suggest considering using DataOutputStream if you want to keep things simple.

To perform your example you can do

```
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(
    new BufferedOutputStream(
        new FileOutputStream("~/myfile")));
// Write in ASCII
out.write("This is a header\n".getBytes());
// Write a 32-bit int
out.writeInt(6);
//Write a float in binary
out.writeFloat(4.5f);

out.flush(); // the buffer.
```

Comment: That's great ! I'll try that and come back to you for the results ! Thank you :)

Comment: Isn't the first line more like:
    'DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(**new** FileOutputStream("~/myfile")));'  ?

Comment: Old code:
- Writing the file in ASCII: 844ms
- Writing the file in Binary: 4767ms
New code: (your solution)
- Writing the file in ASCII: 799ms
- Writing the file in Binary: **80ms**
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Could you give me a little more details on the 3 different classes:
DataOutputStream, BufferedOutputStream, and FileOutputStream ?
What is the role of each ?

Comment: @matthieu you can read the Java doc for details; FileOutputStream writes to a file, BufferedOutputStream buffers the output stream and DataOutputStream provides methods for writing primitives and text to a binary stream.

Comment: All right, I think I understand now. I wasn't sure about the necessity of the BuffereredOutputStream.
It is used to avoid writing to file too often, and instead buffers the data, and writes it to disk by hunks. Am I correct ?

Comment: @matthieu system calls are expensive so if you buffer small data writes/reads you can get a significant performance boost.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought :)